# Save dat.gui presets for dynamically added controls?

Tags: javascript, json, dat.gui

I'm dynamically adding controls to a dat.gui interface, but the "save settings" functionality doesn't recognize them.

```
var mygui = new dat.GUI();
mygui.remember(mygui);

// standard way of adding a control
mygui.control1 = 0.0;
var control = mygui.add(mygui, 'control1', -1, 1);

// adding controls dynamically
var myArray = ['control2', 'control3'];
var controls = [];
for (x in myArray) {
    controls[myArray[x]] = 0.0;
    var newControl = mygui.add(controls, myArray[x], -1, 1);
}
```

The controls all work as expected, but when I click the gear icon, the settings JSON only contains the first control, or any other controls I add in the normal way:

```
{
  "preset": "Default",
  "closed": false,
  "remembered": {
    "Default": {
      "0": {
        "control1": 0.5,
      }
    }
  },
  "folders": {}
}
```

I assume I'm confusing the remember() functionality somehow, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines in the for loop should be:

```
mygui[myArray[x]] = 0.0;
var newControl = mygui2.add(mygui, myArray[x], -1, 1);
```

The first parameter of the `add` function performs two functions: it is both the **source** of the second parameter (the name of the control to be added, which in this case is myArray[x]) but also the **destination**. You can store the control names wherever you like, but if the first parameter isn't the gui, the `remember()` function won't know about the controls, and they won't be added to the gui's `__rememberedObjects` attribute or saved in the JSON object.

Comment: Brilliant answer! If somebody happens to actually *want* the GUI to *not* remember a certain setting, they should additionally set `newControl.isModified = function() { return false; };` to prevent it from showing the star next to the preset name.