# What is the meaning of the third parameter in this dat.gui add function?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dat.gui

I am quite new with `dat.GUI`. I've been reading dat.gui's questions and answers in stackoverflow. I have one question from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844557/how-to-insert-variables-to-dat-gui-with-an-array/24393261#24393261).

What is the meaning of the third argument in the `gui.add` function? i.e. `A[i]`

```
for (var i=1; i<7; i++) {
    controller_names[i] = A[i];
    gui.add(controller_names, i, A[i]);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd and higher arguments of the `add` function is for additional parameters to a given control. Example, if the control is a slider, it will be min & max, like:

```
gui.add(gui, 'Horizontale', 0, 600);
```

For check box control (boolean property, like A[i]), the third argument has no effect.

You can look at the definition of `dat.controllers.factory` in the [source code of dat.gui](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.js), where all controllers are created.

Comment: Thanks very much manji. For me it has a strange coding style. Anyway, your answers is clear, "For check box control [...] has no effect". May you know the answers to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191484/dat-gui-function-invocation-with-parameters) as well?