# Dat.gui function invocation with parameters?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dat.gui

I am quite new with `dat.gui`. According to [this little tutorial](https://dat-gui.googlecode.com/git-history/dbb4fa0ef0428380044e825470e788dec1e37b86/index.html), you can invoke an object's function from the gui, just passing it to the gui's `add` function:

```
gui.add(fizzyText, 'explode');
```

Is it possible to pass arguments to the `explode` function?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't pass arguments to a button's function. What do you want to do exactly? Use the same function for multiple buttons?

Comment: Yes manji, I know I can get a similar behavior with the "onChange" callback. But I just wanted to be sure there is no other way to go. :-) If you write it as an answer, I will mark as best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to pass arguments to a button's function. You can however access other properties of your object in that function:

```
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.name = "name1",
    this.score = 9,
    this.check = function() {
        if(self.score >= 5) { // access to the score property
            alert('you pass!');
        } else {
            alert('try again.');
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass some arguments to explode() if you create through **Function.bind()** a copy of this function.

```
gui.add({explode : fizzyText.explode.bind(this, param_1, param_2)}, "explode");
```

Further information to [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

I also had to do it, to reuse my function and it worked fine for me like that :)